# Redirect in javascript phonegap

Tags: redirect, cordova

I have a problem i tried every possible thing to redirect from my index page to another .html file. window.open, window.location, `window.location.href` but i only get a `?` at the end of my URL. This is my code:

```
function login() {
   var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
   var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

   if(username=='admin' && password=='123') {
     window.location = "phonegap/menu.html";
   }
   else {
      alert('Wrong pw or username!');
   }
```

This is a picture of the result, with every possible function that exist.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT689.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can redirect with below code also and Please for testing use live url

```
window.location = "https://www.google.co.in/";

var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: It is still not working, like i said.. None of those function are working for me. What do you mean with live URL?